# commanButton on notificationBar does not respond to action

Tags: primefaces, action, notification-bar

I am dealing with Primefaces and using notificationBar as Login Menu for my site. But the commandButton on notificationBar only responds to *bar.hide()*. I want to redirect the user to sign up page if he/she is not a registered user with a button named *Sign Up*. If I move the button to another panel it responds. Any help please ? The code is as follows:

```
    <p:notificationBar position="top" effect="slide" widgetVar="bar" style="height:195px;border-bottom:8px solid #DF431A;">  
            <p:panelGrid id="options" columns="1" style="margin-top:-5px;margin-right:150px">
                <h:outputText value="Sign Up" 
                              style="font-size:20px;" />

                <p:commandButton style="float:right;width:100%" value="Sign Up" onclick="bar.hide()" action="sign_up" type="button" />
            </p:panelGrid>
    </p:notificationBar>
```

P.S: I have tried onclick, window location etc.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you solve it already?

Comment: Yes I have, but since I don't believe it is a proper solution I did not write it here. I have declared panelGrid in a different h:form (I have removed the general h:from which comprises notificationBar). Now I have a h:form for every panelGrid (or commandButton). And this solved my problem.